# How do I display an angular directive within a angular-bootstrap popover?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, popover, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an angularJS directive which I want to show as a popover using [Angular Bootstrap Popover](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/popover)
When I try it, the popover just shows the directive tag. (Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/GCY8sMMPKKLa8jZ6GrwL?p=preview)
Any pointers are greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have directives inside HTML attributes.  I suggest that you create a directive that passes the popover specific attributes to your target element.

Answer (score 0):

I think popover just doesn't work with HTML. replacing your directive's tag with a regular `div` tag doesn't work either.